# MySQL | Select two max. values from one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have ID (TV-Series ID), T (Translator ID), S (Season), E (Episode)

I need to convert this:

```
| ID | T | S | E |  
| 1  | 1 | 1 | 2 |  
| 1  | 1 | 1 | 3 |  
| 1  | 2 | 1 | 3 |  
| 2  | 3 | 2 | 1 |  
| 2  | 3 | 3 | 1 |
```

Into this:

```
| ID | T | S | E |  
| 1  | 1 | 1 | 3 |  
| 1  | 2 | 1 | 3 |  
| 2  | 3 | 3 | 1 |
```

My idea:

```
SELECT `ID, `T`, `S`, `E`
FROM `UPDATE`
WHERE
`S` = (SELECT MAX(`S`) FROM `UPDATE` WHERE `ID` = `ID`)
AND `E` = (SELECT MAX(`E`) FROM `UPDATE` WHERE `ID` = `ID` AND `S` = (SELECT MAX(`S`) FROM `UPDATE` WHERE `ID` = `ID`))
GROUP BY `ID`, `T`
ORDER BY `TIMESTAMP` DESC
```

Comment: Please explain your logic.

Comment: What's the criteria for your results?  That is, what values are you looking to get in your result set?  Also, what does your query produce?  Does it work?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I need records with max S and E together.

Comment: My query is not work, because I do not know how to use the same ID in subquery.

Comment: What if you have (S,E) pairs of (3,1) and (1,3)? Is (1, 4) > (3, 3)?

Comment: I need to get last episodes for each serial.

Comment: Get max S (Season) and then get max E (Episode) from this S (Season)

Comment: Uueerdo, No. (3, 3) > (1, 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would work. You need to first identify the max S for each ID and T. Once you've identified those, you can join back to the original table on all three fields to get the max E.

```
   SELECT A.ID, A.T, A.S, MAX(B.E) as E
    FROM (
    SELECT ID, T, MAX(S) AS S
    FROM `UPDATE` U
    GROUP BY ID, T) A
    INNER JOIN `UPDATE` B
    ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.T = B.T AND A.S = B.S
    GROUP BY A.ID, A.T, A.S
```

Comment: @diecode added backticks around UPDATE, which was being interpreted as a command rather than a table name. Try now.

Comment: @diecode actually used singlequotes instead. Corrected to backticks. Not sure if that's exactly the right syntax for mysql though.

Comment: I tried this. MySQL error 'unknown colum'. Also tried \`A\`.\`ID\`

Comment: Awesome! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

using `not exists()` to get the latest season for each pair of `id,t` and `max()` to get the latest episode.

```
select id, t, s, max(e) as e
from tbl
where not exists (
  select 1
  from tbl as i
  where i.id = tbl.id
    and i.t  = tbl.t
    and i.s  > tbl.s
    )
group by id, t, s
```

or using a `left join` as:

```
select tbl.id, tbl.t, tbl.s, max(tbl.e) as e
from tbl 
  left join tbl i
    on i.id = tbl.id
      and i.t  = tbl.t
      and i.s  > tbl.s
where i.id is null
group by tbl.id, tbl.t, tbl.s;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/LAFPS18322

returns

```
+----+---+---+---+
| id | t | s | e |
+----+---+---+---+
|  1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
|  1 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
|  2 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
+----+---+---+---+
```

Comment: I can not use max() in query because it will returns the only one result, but I need max S and E for each T.

Comment: @diecode added a rextester demo so you could see the results return  max S and E for each ID, T

Comment: MySQL execute this too much time, I can not get the response. I try to use with `TIMESTAMP >=  NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: Why MySQL stucks on this query?